# System not able to access other systems

Tags: linux, networking

I have a linux server in which there there are 4 LAN ports, 2 are configured, **10.21.14.160** and **100.200.30.10** whenever I ping from 10 series machines, when both ports are active, it starts looking for 100 series.

Their gateways are, **10.21.14.201** and **100.200.30.201** respectively.

Any solutions for it?

Comment: You have default gateways on both interfaces?  That's not gonna work the way you want it to.  Which interface do you want to use for traffic bound for the internet? Please provide more detail about what you're actually trying to accomplish. And [assuming you don't work for T-Mobile, you should ***not*** be using the 100.128.0.0/9 block for what sounds like an internal network](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-100-128-0-0-1/pft).

Comment: It is intranet setup.  Not internet

Comment: Well, if the machine will be accessing the internet in any way, ever, then **never use an IP address that belongs to someone else**.  In any case, are you able to provide more details about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please show us your current routing table, just to avoid any potential confusion. I also agree with Shane, the only 100-space cleared for private network usage is `100.64.0.0/10`, and only if you're an ISP using it for its intended carrier NAT purposes.

Comment: What does "it starts looking for 100 series" mean?! What is the "it"? And what do you mean by "looking"?

Comment: @Shane Madden post your comment as answer so that i can make it correct answer, i took a clue from your answer, removed the default gateway from 100.200.30.201 and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Having two interfaces on different networks with default gateways is a recipe for headaches.

The default gateway determines the next hop of traffic bound for IP addresses for which there is no other route.

In most deployments where you have multiple interfaces on different subnets, you should have only one default gateway on one specific interface, and if necessary, more specific routes on the other interfaces for traffic on the other network(s).